# Compiled static executable returns "no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, ld

I'm trying to static compile my c++ executable. Everything works fine usually, but I'm trying to compile it statically.

Here is the linker line:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -O3 -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ main.cpp.o xor.cpp.o other.cpp.o -o myprogram -rdynamic -Wl,-Bstatic -lssl -lcrypto -lprotobuf-lite /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.a -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -ldl
```

There are no errors in the compilation. When I try to execute the program:

```
./myprogram
```

I get this:

```
bash: No such file or directory: ./myprogram
```

`ls -la ./myprogram` returns:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 2746921 Feb 10 14:26 ./myprogram
```

What is going on?

Comment: Possibly http://superuser.com/questions/344533

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: remove `-static`. The option forces only static libraries (no shared libs) and as I wanted to link in two shared libraries it made the binary unusable.

Also I don't even think `-static` is valid for executable files.

Comment: `-static` is valid for executable files, it links everything statically. If something is not available as a static library, you should get linking errors.